# Nightwatch selenium client.url never gets done

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm having an issue with my tests I run with Selenium-webdriver, Chromedriver and nightwatch.js. I run two terminal windows, one with selenium and one with the test. I'm running this on a macbook air with macOS Sierra.
My test look like:

```
module.exports = {
'Demo test' : function (browser) {
  browser.url();
  browser.pause(1000);
  browser.maximizeWindow();
  browser.resizeWindow(300, 300);
  browser.maximizeWindow();
  browser.pause(2000);
  browser.url('http://www.google.se').resizeWindow(500, 500);
  browser.end();
 }
};
```

This gives the following output in the terminal when I run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar and then run the test in another terminal window:
test is run like

```
node nightwatch.js tests/demo.js
```

And it gives this output in the selenium terminal window.

```
09:11:21.617 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
09:11:21.663 INFO - Done: [get current url]
09:11:22.680 INFO - Executing: [maximise window])
09:11:22.941 INFO - Done: [maximise window]
09:11:22.950 INFO - Executing: [set window size])
09:11:23.073 INFO - Done: [set window size]
09:11:23.080 INFO - Executing: [maximise window])
09:11:23.565 INFO - Done: [maximise window]
09:11:25.577 INFO - Executing: [get: http://www.google.se])
```

After this nothing more happens. For some reason I don't get a done callback from client.url() when I have a real webpage and just not a empty window.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Same problem, i'm on macOS sierra too (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392128/nightwatch-doesnt-go-to-the-next-instruction)

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you are using selenium 3.0.0. You have not mentioned which browser you are using and what version of its driver you are using.

I tried this code on two settings. Both settings had nightwatch 0.9.8, chromedriver 2.25, Chrome Browser v54. OS was always OSX Sierra 10.12.1. One setting had selenium 2X while the other had selenium 3.0.1

In both settings, your test code executed successfully. So this way it is difficult to help you find a solution to this problem

Here is the nightwatch config

```json
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folders" : "reports",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "tools/selenium3.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "tools/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://www.google.com",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```